# Python multiprocessing: set() in dict() doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, set, multiprocessing

When there is a set() in dict(), the .add() function doesn't work.

```py
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
shared_dict = manager.dict()

def worker1(d, key):
    if key not in shared_dict:
        d[key] = {'0': set(), '1': set()}

def worker2(d, key):
    if key not in shared_dict:
        d[key] = {'0': set(), '1': set()}

        d[key]['0'].add(1)
        d[key]['1'].add(2)


process1 = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=worker1, args=[shared_dict, 'a'])
process2 = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=worker2, args=[shared_dict, 'b'])

process1.start()
process2.start()
process1.join()
process2.join()
```

I expected the following output:

```py
{'a': {'1': set([]), '0': set([])}, 'b': {'1': (2), '0': (1)}}
```

instead of:

```py
{'a': {'1': set([]), '0': set([])}, 'b': {'1': set([]), '0': set([])}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read about your problem in [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects), which says:

> If standard (non-proxy) list or dict objects are contained in a
> referent, modifications to those mutable values will not be propagated
> through the manager because the proxy has no way of knowing when the
> values contained within are modified.

So, under "normal" circumstances if you create a new reference to an object and modify it, the modification is applied to the object no matter which reference you use to modify it:

```
a = set([1])
b = a
b.add(2)
print(a, b)    # {1, 2} {1, 2}
```

In the manager, however, the modifications are not applied to the object for the quoted reason. Nevertheless, you can create a new reference to the object, change the value form there and then reassign the modified version to the dict.

```
import multiprocessing

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
shared_dict = manager.dict()

def worker1(d, key):
    d.setdefault(key, {'0': set(), '1': set()})

def worker2(d, key):
    d.setdefault(key, {'0': set(), '1': set()})
    
    buffer = d[key]
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(buffer.items()):
        buffer[k].add(i)
    d[key] = buffer
        

process1 = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=worker1, args=[shared_dict, 'a'])
process2 = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=worker2, args=[shared_dict, 'b'])


process1.start()
process2.start()
process1.join()
process2.join()
```

Btw, use `dict.setdefault` refactor these `if` statements.